# jcrop do not cropping what is in preview window

Tags: jquery, jcrop

We are using jcrop to crop images for user Accounts.following settings for jcrop we are using.The final cropped image we get is little bit zoomed In.We are using aspect ratio of 1.and boxSize Attributes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
    var jcrop_api,
        boundx,
        boundy,

        // Grab some information about the preview pane
        $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
        $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
        $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

        xsize = $pcnt.width(),
        ysize = $pcnt.height();

    $('#target').Jcrop({
        onChange: updatePreview,
        onSelect: updatePreview,
        bgColor: 'white',
        bgOpacity: .4,
        addClass: 'jcrop-light',
        boxWidth: 450,
        boxHeight: 400,
        aspectRatio: 1
    }, function () {
        // Use the API to get the real image size
        var bounds = this.getBounds();
        boundx = bounds[0];
        boundy = bounds[1];
        // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
        jcrop_api = this;
        jcrop_api.setSelect([0, 0, 200, 200]);
        jcrop_api.setOptions({
            bgFade: true
        });
        jcrop_api.ui.selection.addClass('jcrop-selection');

        // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
        $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
    });

    function updatePreview(c) {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
        $('#x2').val(c.x2);
        $('#y2').val(c.y2);
        var rx = 200 / c.w; // 200 - preview box size
        var ry = 200 / c.h;
        if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
            var rx = xsize / c.w;
            var ry = ysize / c.h;

            $pimg.css({
                width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
            });
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're cropping avatar/profile images I would strongly recomend using [Guillotine](http://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine).

It's a very lightweight plugin that allows to crop, zoom and rotate images, it has touch support and it's responsive (fluid). It's perfect for cropping profile pictures ([demo](http://matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine)).

I hope it's what you need and that it helps you solve this issue.